# Webpack config html-webpack-plugin with PHP

Tags: php, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

In my webpack structure i'm using html-webpack-plugin to generate my html files, etc., the problem is that I want to make something on page,
and in this situation I want to use PHP. How can I make it work properly? I was looking on the Internet but I could not find anything.

Here is my webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const {
    distPath,
    srcPath
} = require('./webpack.config.paths');

const {
    selectedPreprocessor
} = require('./webpack.config.preprocessor');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './' + srcPath + '/js/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, distPath),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: selectedPreprocessor.fileRegexp,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: false,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: selectedPreprocessor.loaderName,
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /app.*\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'scss/index.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: false,
            //inject: "head",
            template: './' + srcPath + '/content/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            myPageHeader: 'Hello World',
        }),
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 6):

This is more a comment than an answer, but I'm lack of reputation to comment. Your question needs to be clarified on what exactly is the aim you pursue - do you want to generate PHP page using webpack or do you want to use PHP under webpack dev server.

**The first case** is my typical usecase - I use webpack to generate PHP pages, which will be deployed onto shared hosting. Plus, I use Pug template engine - it's quite complicated to make Pug and PHP friends, but Pug fits me perfectly for my common purposes. To compile, I use `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

Example:

`webpack.config.js` (only key part, considered that you've installed and imported dependencies)

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'pug-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: `./test.pug`,
      filename: `test.php`,
      foo: 'bar'
    })
  ]
}
```

`test.pug` In Pug, you are going to insert PHP as interpolation or plain text (as described in [docs](https://pugjs.org) at sections "Interpolation" and "Plain Text").

```
- var { foo } = htmlWebpackPlugin.options
section.my-section
  .                                      // <- Plain Text Insertion
    <?php
    $sample_class = "sample-class";
    $foo = "!{foo}";                     // <- Interpolation
    ?>
  p.default-class(class!='<?php echo $sample_class; ?>')   // <- Here default class of <p> placed right after dot, and PHP class variable placed as an unsafe argument
    .
      <?php echo $foo; ?>
```

Then webpack gives me output as follows:

`test.php`

```
<section class="my-section">

  <?php
  $sample_class = "sample-class";
  $foo = "bar";                       
  ?>

  <p class="default-class <?php echo $sample_class; ?>"><?php echo $foo; ?></p>

</section>
```

If this is what you want, it works.

**The second case** is merely impossible - in this case you may want to use devserver for webpacked pages and (for example) XAMPP server for PHP pages, and these 2 servers must listen to different ports (`http://localhost:8080` for WDS and `http://localhost:80` or just `http://localhost` for XAMPP ).